# how do I use the facebook api to modify a video title or description?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How can I update the title/description of a previously updated video?  I am using python and pyfacebook... but any starting point would be fine and I can write it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to edit a Video object at all with the Graph API at the moment.  You can't create objects through the API, therefore I don't think you can edit or modify existing ones either.